# How to pipe a the output of find to another find invocation

Tags: find, pipe, xargs

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -P4 find -name 'war' -type d
```

I would like to create a list of directory names, null-terminated, and then pass this list to xargs, which for each directory name calls find using a pool of 4 processes.

My problem is: How do I access stdin in the piped-to find command? Something like

```
find <STDIN> -name 'war' -type d
```

Comment: You can use `-I SOME_SYMBOLS` parameter for `xargs` to construct `find SOME_SYMBOLS -name ...` but you can do what you want by 1 `find` command only.

Comment: @costas I know I could use 1 find for this but I would like to process the directories in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} -P4 find "{}" -name "war" -type d
```

better way is exclude `.` path:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -path .  -type d -print0 |
xargs -0 -I "{}"  find "{}" -name "war" -type d
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `-mindepth 1` instead of `-not -path .`like Anton suggested. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: If you use the output of `xargs -P4` then you need to address mixing of output. See example of the problem http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-xargs-AND-GNU-Parallel

Answer (score 3):

Find cannot read its path from stdin, you cannot specify `-` like with many other programs.

I recommend that you use GNU parallel to run things in parallel:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0  | parallel -0 --jobs 4 \
    find {} -name "war" -type d
```

Please note the added `-mindepth 1` to the first find. If you don't include that, the current directory (`.`) will be passed in to one of the finds as well and you will get double results.

```
$ mkdir a b c d e
$ mkdir b/war c/war
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0  | parallel -0 --jobs 4 \
    find {} -name "war" -type d
./b/war
./c/war
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0  | parallel -0 --jobs 4 \
    find {} -name "war" -type d
./c/war
./b/war
./c/war
./b/war
```

Comment: I'd like offer `find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type d -print0` instead `-mindepth 1`

Comment: @Costas That would skip directories with a name starting with `.` unless you take special precautions for the expansion.